# How to debug emacs config / need to rerun org-mode after startup

Tags: org-mode, debugging, debug, window-configuration

I run emacs on Windows and I start with this command:

```
C:\path-to\emacs.exe -q --load "C:/path-to-git-tracked-config-folder/.emacs" --debug-init
```

Emacs starts without error from --debug-init.

When I open a .org file the major mode is set correctly to org-mode.

But some essential settings are not applied untill I manually run `M-x org-mode` (font settings, hide the stars and activate `org-bullets`). Also the agenda is empty untill the manual run.

How can I track down the bug in my config responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean: you start emacs as above with `--debug-init`, then open an Org mode file, the major mode is set correctly, but the initialization is incomplete? Then you do `M-x org-mode` in that buffer and the initialization is complete? Or do you mean something else? I can't quite understand the sequence of actions: can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes exactly: 1. Start with `--debug-init` 2. open an org-file where org major mode is set correctly 3. Have to run `M-x org-mode` to see all the settings correctly applied. No errors from `--debug-init`. If I run `M-x org-agenda` before manually running `M-x org-mode` the agenda is empty. Only after running `M-x org-mode` manually (and a refresh of the persistent agenda) everything works as expected.